# Razor CSHTML IF statement

Tags: razor

Anyone here that can help me? I have the following code:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{ 
    var node = @Model.NodeById(1257);
}
    <div class="Top10"> 
    <h1>Newest</h1>

@foreach (var article in node.Descendants().Where("Visible && (NodeTypeAlias = \"Article\" || NodeTypeAlias = \"sergrein\" || NodeTypeAlias = \"solomyndagrein\")").OrderBy("createDate desc").Take(10))
    {                   
         <a href="@article.Url"><h2>@article.createDate.ToString("dd/MM") | @article.title</h2></a>    
    }

    </div>
```

What I want is: if @article.title is longer than e.g. 10 characters, it needs to return the 10 characters followed by ... (for example: "this_is_a_..."). If the @article.title is shorter than 10 characters, it can just show the full title length.
How can this truncating be done?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@(article.title.Length > 10 ? (article.title.Substring(0,10) + " ...") : article.title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd say do this in your Model, but it looks like you're using Umbraco's model.

So you could just do:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{ 
    var node = @Model.NodeById(1257);
}
<div class="Top10"> 
<h1>Newest</h1>

@foreach (var article in node.Descendants().Where("Visible && (NodeTypeAlias = \"Article\" || NodeTypeAlias = \"sergrein\" || NodeTypeAlias = \"solomyndagrein\")").OrderBy("createDate desc").Take(10))
{                
    {
        var title = article.title;
        if (title.Length > 10)
            title = title.Substring(0,10) + "...";
    }
    <a href="@article.Url"><h2>@article.createDate.ToString("dd/MMM") | @title</h2></a>    
}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this shall help,

```
@{
if(article.title.ToString().Length > 10)
 {
  article.title = article.title.Substring(0,10) + " ..."; //the format you desire
 }
 else
 {
  article.title; // default
 }
 }
```