# How to style a <div> tag according to user input mvc5

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to style my jumbotron according to the theme that is chosen by the user. I want to use if-statements but I don't know the correct way in doing this in CSHTML.

I know the following code is incorrect, can anyone help show me how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
themes = db.Themes.ToList();

foreach (var item in themes)
{
    if (item.themeImage != null)
    {
        string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(item.themeImage);
        imageSource1 = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);
    }

    if (theme == beach && item.themeID == 1)
    {
        <text>
            <div class="jumbotron" id="@item.themeID" img src="@item.themeImage">
        </text>
    }
    else if (theme == animals && item.themeID == 2)
    {
        <text>
            <div class="jumbotron" id="@item.themeID" style="background-image:@imageSource1; background-size:cover">
        </text>
    }
    else if (theme == kitchen && item.themeID == 3)
    {
        <text>
            <div class="jumbotron" id="@item.themeID" style="background-image:@imageSource1; background-size:cover">
        </text>
    }
}
```

The theme and styling of the jumbotron should be dependent on what the user chooses.

Comment: If you're willing to use JQuery, you can use $('#selector').addClass().

Comment: To reduce comparison overhead I would add an enum for theme: example `if(theme.ThemeType == Themes.ThemeTypes.beach) { \\Do Work }` This way you are comparing a much smaller value. For your question though I would recommend the use of jQuery and it's addClass function if you can do it. Otherwise in your cshtml file you can insert c# logic with the "@" symbol. [Here is another question that uses it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244597/razor-cshtml-if-statement)

Comment: Also consider using Html.RenderAction() or Html.Partial() for simplicity and modularity

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small function and call that for getting the correct style.

You can do that in your cshtml

```
@{
    string GetStylePerTheme(int themeId)
    {
        switch(themeId)
        {
            case 1:
                return "color: red;";
            case 2:
                return "color: blue;";
            default:
                return "color: black;";
        }
    }
}
```

and use this for html (same cshtml)

```
<text>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="@item.themeID" style="@GetStylePerTheme(item.themeID)">
</text>
```

Now if you want this to be clean and reusable across multiple pages, create a custom helper (a simple static method, practiacally)

```
    public static string GetStylePerTheme(this HtmlHelper helper, int themeId)
        {
            switch(themeId)
            {
                case 1:
                    return "color: red;";
                case 2:
                    return "color: blue;";
                default:
                    return "color: black;";
            }
        }
```

and for cshtml

```
<text>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="@item.themeID" style="@Html.GetStylePerTheme(item.themeID)">
</text>
```

Extending HtmlHelper is optional.